# Adding new column based upon keywords in another column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a massive dataframe and I'm trying to categorise each row based on a column called 'name' which is a string. A new column 'sub_category' should be, for example, 'Climate' if the column 'name' contains 'environment', 'climate', 'global warming', etc.

I have tried creating a list containing the keywords for climate, then trying to define a function to return me values based on upon the list whih would then be applied:

```
climate = ['environment', 'climate', 'global warming']

def sub_cat (row):
    if row['name'].str.contains('|'.join(climate), case=False):
        return 'Climate'

df.apply (lambda row: sub_cat(row), axis=1)
```

I could def a function to have multiple if statements to catgeorise this but it does not work as 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```py
climate = ['environment', 'climate', 'global warming']

def sub_cat(row):    
    """ Categorize the rows based on the words in the name.   
        Convert all chars to lowercase to check"""
    if any(st in row['name'].lower() for st in climate): 
        return 'Climate'
    #elif:
        # ...your other conditions 
    else:
        return None

df['my_category'] = df.apply(sub_cat, axis=1)
```

Comment: This seems to work! I still get "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" this though

Comment: That warning msg usually means that your df is a VIEW of another DataFrame. 
It is just a reminder to notify you that, with views, you are not changing the original DataFrame.
Investigate with "print(df._is_view)".

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a big dataset, try to avoid using `pd.apply()`, it is prolonged (very slow). [you can find here an article about that](https://towardsdatascience.com/avoiding-apply-ing-yourself-in-pandas-a6ade4569b7f).

Therefore, we could use `pd.assign()` with `lambda`.
Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
climate = ['environment', 'climate', 'global warming']

df = (
    df
    .assign(category = lambda df_: np.select([df_.Name.str.contains('|'.join(climate),case=False)
                                              ,~df_.Name.str.contains('|'.join(climate),case=False)], ["Climate", "Not Climate"]))
) 
print(df[["Name", "category"]])
```

I have used as well Numpy since it is super fast (in comparison to pd.apply), `np.select()` acts as an if statement but in a faster manner.

I created a sample dataset, and here is the output I got:

[image]

I hope this helps!